# Difference between collection and array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a collection like

```
const collection = [{url: '/string/'}, {url: '/string-2/'}]
```

and an `array` of `string`

```
const strings = ['/string/']
```

I'm trying to make the difference between the two in a way that the result is

```
const difference = [{url: '/string-2/'}]
```

I tried with lodash `_.filter`

```
const difference = _.filter(collection, obj => strings.every(url => url !== obj.self));
```

but it doesn't work. Tried with `._partition` but it does return multiple arrays while I'd like to have just the collection without the object

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without lodash, by using `.filter()` and check whether the current object's `url` is included in the `strings` array like so:

```js
const collection = [{url: '/string/'}, {url: '/string-2/'}];
const strings = ['/string/'];

const difference = collection.filter(({url}) => strings.includes(url));
console.log(difference);
```

... or, if each `url` is unique, a more efficient way would be to create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where each key in the map is a `url`, which points to your object. Then `.map()` over your `strings` array like so:

```js
const collection = [{url: '/string/'}, {url: '/string-2/'}];
const strings = ['/string/'];

const collection_map = new Map(collection.map(obj => [obj.url, obj]));
const difference = strings.map(str => collection_map.get(str));
console.log(difference);
```

With lodash, you can apply the same logic as above by using your `_.filter()` method with `_.includes()` like so:

```js
const collection = [{url: '/string/'}, {url: '/string-2/'}];
const strings = ['/string/'];

const difference = _.filter(collection, obj => _.includes(strings, obj.url));
console.log(difference);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`differenceWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith):

```
const collection = [{url: '/string/'}, {url: '/string-2/'}]

const strings = ['/string/']

result = _.differenceWith(collection, strings, (a, b) => a.url === b)

console.log(result) // [ { url: '/string-2/' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple `Array.prototype.includes()` & `Array.prototype.filter()`, like this:

```
const collection = [{url: '/string/'}, {url: '/string-2/'}];

const strings = ['/string/'];

const difference = collection.filter(c => strings.includes(c.url) );
console.log(difference)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through vanilla JS. The necessary methods are [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const collection = [{url: '/string/'}, {url: '/string-2/'}];
const strings = ['/string/'];

const difference = collection.filter(({url}) => strings.some(s=> url !== s));
console.log(res);
```